# The button on UIImageView is not clickable

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibutton

[image]

[image]

I create `UIImageView` programmatically,and add one `UIButton` on it. But the button is not clickable.

When I click the button `My account`, it will display like the second photo. The `UIImageView` will show up and there is a button `My profile` on it. But `My profile` doesn't work when I click it. When I click `My account` again, the `UIImageView` will disappear as I expect( `MY profile` will disappear,too)

When revise `action: "clickProfile"` to `action: "clickProfile:"`, it still doesn't work. When I click the button `myAccount`, the `UIImageView` will show up, when I click the button on `UIImageView`, it should prints "work". When I click `myAccount`, the UIImageView will disappear.
Here is all of my code:

```
class userViewController: UIViewController,UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

let picker = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "picker"))

func createPicker()
{
picker.frame = CGRect(x: ((self.view.frame.width / 2) - 143), y: 200, width: 286, height: 291)
picker.alpha = 0
picker.hidden = true
picker.userInteractionEnabled = true


self.view.addSubview(picker)


}


func clickProfile(sender:UIButton!)
{
print("should work")

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.picker.userInteractionEnabled = true
createPicker()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func myAccount(sender: UIButton) {

picker.hidden ? openPicker() : closePicker()
}


func openPicker()
{
self.picker.hidden = false

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
    animations: {
        self.picker.frame = CGRect(x: ((self.view.frame.width / 2) - 143), y: 230, width: 286, height: 291)
        self.picker.alpha = 1
})

var offset = -180

let buttonProfile:UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
buttonProfile.frame = CGRect(x: 140, y: offset, width: 260, height: 43)


buttonProfile.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.85, green: 0.22, blue: 0.71, alpha: 1.0), forState: .Normal)
//  button.setTitleColor(UIColor(rgba: feeling["color"]!), forState: .Normal)
buttonProfile.setTitle("My profile", forState: .Normal)
buttonProfile.tag = 0
buttonProfile.addTarget(self, action: "clickProfile:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

picker.addSubview(buttonProfile)

}

func closePicker()
{
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
    animations: {
        self.picker.frame = CGRect(x: ((self.view.frame.width / 2) - 143), y: 200, width: 286, height: 291)
        self.picker.alpha = 0
    },
    completion: { finished in
        self.picker.hidden = true
    }
)
}

}
```

I already enable `userInteractionEnabled` to be true, but the button on the UIImageView still don't work. How does it happen ?

Comment: What is your Frame of UIbutton and UIImageview? Make sure it will be same, I think Button didnt get exactly frame of UiImageview...Please check Once...

Comment: I think you are missing `:` Try replacing `action: "clickProfile"` with `action: "clickProfile:"`

Comment: action: "clickProfile:" doesn't work for me, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to log you picker and button frame.

From your code, the frame for those control are slightly off, your button frame is supposed to be located inside picker.

```
picker.frame = CGRect(x: ((self.view.frame.width / 2) - 143), y: 200, width: 286, height: 291)

buttonProfile.frame = CGRect(x: 140, y: -180, width: 260, height: 43)
```

lets say you run this on iPhone 5 sim/device with resolution 320 x 568.

lets assume that your `self.view` frame is the same as that.

therefore your picker frame in `self.view` is (17, 200, 286, 290) and your button frame in picker coordinate is (140, -180, 260, 43) and when translated to `self.view` coordinate become (157, 20, 260, 43).

The visual representation for those coordinate is below.
[image]

As you can see, your button (green picture) is not where it is supposed to be, try to modify button frame so that the button is inside your picker (red picture).

Comment: Can you tell me how to make the visual representation for those coordinate ? How to log the frame ? I even don't know how to search online. I was trying to move the UIImageView to the top right conner so that the button can be inside the UIImageView, but I don't know what's the x,y value should be for the UIImageView. (Not move the button, but move the UIImageView)

Comment: You could log the frame using this `print("%@", NSStringFromCGRect(picker.frame)`. As for visual representation, i am using playground and create control with those frame.

Comment: Can you show me how to create control with those frame? I create a playground and call the class or these sub functions, but it doesn't show the results. Can you show me how to call the class can let it show the visual representation like yours?

Comment: Try to follow these tutorial. https://possiblemobile.com/2015/03/prototyping-uiview-animations-swift-playground/

Answer (score 1):

Its not recommended to add a subview to the image view. Even if you do then if the image view is hidden then all its subviews will also be hidden. When a view is hidden userInteraction does not happen anyways.

You should add the button to self.view and place it on top of the image view instead of putting it inside the image view. Try this  code.

```
func createPicker()
{
    picker.frame = CGRect(x: ((self.view.frame.width / 2) - 143), y: 200, width: 286, height: 291)
    picker.alpha = 0
    picker.hidden = true
    picker.userInteractionEnabled = true
    picker.clipsToBounds = false

    self.view.addSubview(picker)

    let offset = 100


    let buttonProfile:UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    buttonProfile.frame = CGRect(x: 140, y: offset, width: 260, height: 43)
    buttonProfile.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.85, green: 0.22, blue: 0.71, alpha: 1.0), forState: .Normal)
    //  button.setTitleColor(UIColor(rgba: feeling["color"]!), forState: .Normal)
    buttonProfile.setTitle("My profile", forState: .Normal)
    buttonProfile.tag = 0
    buttonProfile.addTarget(self, action: "myAccount:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(buttonProfile)


}
```

Your offset for the button was also off screen. I set it to 100 to make it appear on the screen. You can position it as per your requirements.

Comment: picker.hidden is not always be false. It will be true when I click the button "My account". I just update my code. I want to implement drop down menu effects to the button "My account", so I need to set the UIImageView too disappear and appear when I click "My account". My offset for the button works on my screen(The simulator I use is iphone6, it is on the position I expect)

Answer (score 0):

Your picker view alpha is 0 and hidden is true. Remove these

```
picker.alpha = 0
picker.hidden = true
```

lines.

Update this line

```
    buttonProfile.addTarget(self, action: "clickProfile", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

to

```
    buttonProfile.addTarget(self, action: "clickProfile:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: No. I need the picker to be transparent. And revise action: "clickProfile" to action: "clickProfile:" still doesn't work for me.

Comment: The UIImageView should appear when I click another button myAccount. It should disappear when I click myAccount again.

Comment: Use picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() to make it transparent,